# HJImagesToVideo with Swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cgimageref

I am using the source of HJImagesToVideo
https://github.com/HarrisonJackson/HJImagesToVideo

When I compiled the sample code provided by him, it is working fine with Xcode 7.2
but when I am using this in my swift project it is not working and showing some errors on

```
    buffer = [HJImagesToVideo pixelBufferFromCGImage:[array[i] CGImage] size:CGSizeMake(480, 320)]; //line # 212 of HJImagesToVideo.m

    buffer = [HJImagesToVideo crossFadeImage:[array[i] CGImage]
                                                     toImage:[array[i + 1] CGImage]
                                                      atSize:CGSizeMake(480, 320)
                                                   withAlpha:j/framesToFadeCount]; //line # 241 of HJImagesToVideo.m

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempPath, self, nil, nil);  //line # 150 of
```

and the errors are:

> /Users/Raza/my apps/appname/app-name/HJImagesToVideo.m:213:64: No
>   known instance method for selector 'CGImage'

and

> /Users/Raza/my apps/appname/app-name/HJImagesToVideo.m:213:54:
>   Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type
>   'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *') requires a bridged cast

on line # 213 and 241

and on line # 150
error is:

> Users/Raza/my apps/appname/app-name/HJImagesToVideo.m:150:28: Implicit
>   declaration of function 'UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum' is
>   invalid in C99

Can anyone can help me to figure out these problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum is defined in UIKit.
Have you forgot to import UIKit ?

Comment: This is not a big issue, other errors are big issues that i m not able to solve

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried it by myself and importing UIKit fixes the problem. Just add #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> after #import "HJImagesToVideo.h" in _HJImagesToVideo.m_

Comment: I have solved that error
Users/Raza/my apps/appname/app-name/HJImagesToVideo.m:150:28: Implicit declaration of function 'UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum' is invalid in C99

Can you please help me to solve problem on line # 213 and 241?